# setting response of api in useState is null

Tags: reactjs, use-state

On form submit I am calling an API and I am getting a response from API. I want to use that response value in other places. When I debug I can see value in response but while assigning it using useState it is always null which is the default value at first.

```
 const[matterID, setMatterID]= useState(null);
 const[matterName, setMatterName]= useState(null);

const submitHandler= async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setPosting(true);

    axios.post(constants.MATTER_SAVE_URI, {matterModel:matterDetail, prefix:matterDetail.Prefix, suffix:matterDetail.Suffix}, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }})
    .then((response) => {
      setMatterID(prev =>{
        return{...prev, ...response.data.responseData.matterNumberLTB }
      })
  console.log("matteri",matterID);

      setMatterName(response.data.responseData.name);
   //i also tried using this way.
 axios.post(constants.ADD_MEMBER_TO_GROUP + "/" + matterID, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }})
      .then((response) => {
        axios.post(constants.ACCESS_ALL_MEMBER_MATTER + "/" + matterID + "/" + hasAccess, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }})
}
```

Comment: How are you checking it's null afterwards? This looks good `setMatterID(prev =>{`

Comment: Have you logged the `response` object? What does it give you?

Comment: when i check on controller and console it is null

Comment: i have just edited and put console line in above code

Comment: State changes are asynchronous. You can't `console.log` state right after calling it and see new value. Put the `console.log("matteri",matterID);` in the main body of the function to see its latest value

Comment: the `setMatterId` and similar functions from `useState` are async calls so you will not see the update. Can you check your 'response' object?

Comment: my problem is after getting matterid i have to call other api .  i just edited it complete code

Comment: may be i am not calling other api in correct way, i am new to this react.

Comment: @Devatanu can you look at this

Comment: In React, state updates are asynchronous, so you can't console log right after enqueueing an update. `submitHandler` was also declared `async` but you don't run any code asynchronously, i.e. you never `await` any asynchronous code to resolve. The second POST request runs right after the first, essentially concurrently.